# MySQL geom offset testing

Tags: mysql, join, geometry, stored-functions

I'm looking to write an offset function to test in a moving object touches other movable and fixed objects in space.
In order to test this I need to see if their bounding rects intersect.

I would like to test if two movable objects touch like so:
Table car
- id: integer (autoinc primary)
- rect: Linestring
- ...

Table location
- id: integer (autoinc primary)
- car_id: integer
- car_date: date
- car_pos: point
- ...

`FUNCTION MyDB.OffsetRect(pLineString GEOMETRY, pOffset POINT)
  RETURNS geometry
    BEGIN

    declare Result LineString;

    declare P1 Point;

    declare P2 point;

    declare P3 point;

    declare P4 point;

    set Result = ENVELOPE(pLineString);  /Make sure we are dealing with a rect/

    set P1 = POINTN(Result,1);

    set p1 = Point(X(p1)+X(pOffset),Y(p1)+Y(pOffset));

    set P2 = POINTN(Result,2);

    set p2 = Point(X(p2)+X(pOffset),Y(p2)+Y(pOffset));

    set P3 = POINTN(Result,3);

    set p3 = Point(X(p3)+X(pOffset),Y(p3)+Y(pOffset));

    set P4 = POINTN(Result,4);

    set p4 = Point(X(p4)+X(pOffset),Y(p4)+Y(pOffset));

    set Result = LineString(p1,p2,p3,p4);

    RETURN Result;

    END`

But I'm stuck at what query to use to see if two cars intersect in time.
something like.

```
SELECT location.id, location2.id FROM location
INNER JOIN car ON (car.id = location.car_id)
INNER JOIN location location2 ON (location.id <> location2.id)
INNER JOIN car car2 ON (car2.id = location2.car_id AND car.id <> car2.id)
WHERE location.car_date BETWEEN date_sub(now(),INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND date_add(now(),INTERVAL 1 DAY)
AND location2.car_date BETWEEN date_sub(now(),INTERVAL 1 DAY) and date_add(now(),INTERVAL 1 DAY)
AND      MBRIntersects(OffsetRect(car.rect,location.car_pos),OffsetRect(car2.rect,location2.car_pos));
```

However this does not work, what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intersect.. you mean both parked in the same place within the space of 48 hours from each other (your time ranges are 48 hours).

> WHERE **location**.car_date BETWEEN date_sub(now(),INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND date_add(now(),INTERVAL 1 DAY)
>   AND **location**.car_date BETWEEN date_sub(now(),INTERVAL 1 DAY) and date_add(now(),INTERVAL 1 DAY)

You have used the same alias twice in a row

Comment: 48 hours - Yeah, I simplified it a bit for testing.

Comment: Other than that it's OK? Ghee I was close then!